# How to edit a document link in a Sharepoint Library without losing data in other columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, links

I have a Document Library in Sharepoint (online or 365).  I have added links to a lot of documents that are stored in that same library (we did this to make it group/sort/view the way we need it to).  Now I find that we used the wrong link (why are there so freaking many different links available???).  I need to change the links, but I don't want to lose all of the data in the other columns.  We have looked at it and do not see where to change just the link address without losing the other data.  Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

TIA,
Clay

Comment: Whether you add links in the column or add links in the contents of the documents?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand...